# ldconfig reports libraries "have same soname but different type"

Tags: centos

I just updated my servers from CentOS 5.5 to CentOS 5.6, and now when I run `ldconfig`, I get these:

```
ldconfig: libraries libdchtvm32.so.5 and libdchtvm64.so in directory /usr/lib have same soname but different type.
ldconfig: libraries libdchcfl32.so and libdchcfl64.so.5 in directory /usr/lib have same soname but different type.
ldconfig: libraries libdchbas32.so.5 and libdchbas64.so.5 in directory /usr/lib have same soname but different type.
ldconfig: libraries libdchtvm64.so and libdchtvm64.so.5 in directory /usr/lib have same soname but different type.
```

I would like to know two things... should I care about this, and if so, what should I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something (srvadmin from Dell, after a quick Google search) has decided to put its 64-bit libraries in `/usr/lib`, which is incorrect; 64-bit libraries belong in `/usr/lib64` or the like. Run `rpm -qfi` against the files and make sure the packages are correct for the distro.

Comment: ...for the distro and / or the arch.

Comment: After uninstalling the 32-bit Dell libs, the issue has abated..

Comment: That's fine, but keep in mind that the 64-bit libs are still in the wrong place.

Comment: Good catch, I had not considered that the libs were in the worng place. I guess my ignorance is showing through. How would you suggest I go about moving them to the right place? Is it as simple as relocating them to /usr/lib64?

Comment: It might be, but normally the package is responsible for putting them in the right place. If it doesn't do so then I'd file a bug report with Dell.